# Python cx_Oracle "32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found""

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, instantclient

I downloaded the Oracle Instant Client and specified the Path in environment variable as in the first screenshot.
[image]

cx_Oracle is imported successfully as shown in the second screenshot.
[image]

I was trying to connect to Oracle DB hosted in AWS using the code as below:
[image]

The log message returns:

> 32-bit Oracle Client library cannot be loaded: "The specified module could not be found".

Is my argument for `cx_Oracle.connect` or my path in the environment variables wrong? Python, WHL and Instant Client are all 32-bits.

Comment: I've embedded your images into your post. Just a friendly tip: Write code, commands and error messages as text, not as images. As you can see, the text in your images is pretty much unreadable. :o)

Comment: This happened the same with me with Oracle on Linux. Follow the link in the error which maintains further instructions per operating system.

Answer (score 0):

From you’re screenshot you seem to use a 32bits python, if yes you also need to use a 32bits Oracle Instant client. Here you’re 32bits Python try to find 32bits oracle libraries and can’t find them.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Instant Client require the presence of the correct Visual Studio redistributable according to documentation of installation: https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#windows. Please check dependences dlls of oci.dll on your system.